# How to execute shell script in cygwin?

Tags: windows, cygwin, shell-script

I store name.sh under C:\Documents and Settings\user when i type sh name.sh in Cygwin,

```
sh: testing.sh: No such file or directory
```

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335262/how-to-execute-shell-script-in-cygwin).

Answer (score 3):

Is that the actual output?  If so, it's looking for another script called `testing.sh`.

`testing.sh` needs to be in a directory listed in the `PATH` variable, or you have to run it using a full path, e.g. `./testing.sh` or `~/user/testing.sh`.

Also don't forget to make `testing.sh` executable by running `chmod +x testing.sh`.

Comment: Sorry,actually there is only name.sh involved, typing error

Comment: That's OK.  It's easy to make mistakes when typing.  That's why it's better to always post the actual output.  Or if you need to hide some sensitive information, copy paste into Notepad, do a Find/Replace, then post that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in C:\Documents and Settings\user when you're running it, try:

```
./name.sh
```

If you're not in that directory, you'll need to either change directory there or prepend the command with the location.  Here's how to change directory to c:\documents and settings\user

```
cd /cygdrive/c/"Documents and Settings"/User
```

You can see which directory you're currently in with the following command, I believe:

```
pwd
```

Comment: I think you may have missed the fact that there are two different filenames involved.